# Excel Table Objects get invisible and lose data after re-opening map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, excel, mapping

I had a case when I had to Insert many Excel tables in the Map Layout and it worked perfectly, exported perfectly, etc. But when I saved it, closed the map and came back to it later ALL Excel tables disappeared. Moreover, if you click where the table should be, the table gets selected, but there is nothing besides the outline, no data, no background. Almost have a feeling that it got converted from Excel object to Draw object, since I can put background to it.
Any ideas, what could be wrong with it?
PS: I am using 10.2.2 ArcGIS and 2010 Excel

Comment: Any chance you are working across network drives?  I see this happen when folders aren't syncing properly.

Comment: No, I don't. But, how would that matter anyway? I use Insert=>Object=>Create New=>Excel Spreadsheet and then enter the data I need. So it is not really linked to anything.

Comment: OK I wasn't clear on what exactly you are doing with Excel Tables.  I sometimes import data from Excel, which can lead to blank tables being shown when network folders aren't syncing properly (that occurs for non-Excel data too though).